# How can I speed up my connection to a ble device?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing a flutter app capable of connecting with a ble device and returning some data from the device. Everything works, but when it connects, takes a bit longer than expected. Is there a way to make it faster? I'm using flutter_reactive_ble package and I already applied this line of code `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` and I'm checking that the BLE status returns ready before the operations.

Note: This happens usually at the first connection when opening the app. After that it connects pretty fast.

I'll post my code for the connection part:

```
  void _startScan() async {
    // await checkStatus();

    String deviceName = globals.controller.text.toUpperCase();
    refreshScreen();
    globals.logTexts = "${globals.logTexts}Scanning for $deviceName\n";
    globals.scanning = true;

    PermissionStatus permission;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      permission = await LocationPermissions().requestPermissions();
      if (permission == PermissionStatus.granted) globals.goForIt = true;
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      globals.goForIt = true;
    }
    if (globals.goForIt) {
      globals.foundDevices = [];
      log('----- SCANNING FOR $deviceName DEVICE -----');
      log(globals.controller.text);

      globals.scanStream = globals.flutterReactiveBle.scanForDevices(
        scanMode: ScanMode.lowLatency,
        withServices: [], //GETS ALL SERVICES
      ).listen(
        (device) async {
          // log('$device');
          if (device.name.length > 0) log(device.name);
          if (device.name == deviceName.toUpperCase()) {
            log(device.name.toString());
            globals.foundDevices.add(device);
            await connectToDeviceFun();
            _stopScan();
            globals.scanning = false;
            globals.logTexts = "${globals.logTexts}Found $deviceName\n";
            setState(
              () {
                globals.discoveredDevice = device;
                globals.foundDeviceWaitingToConnect = true;
              },
            );
          }
        },
      );
    } else {
      await showNoPermissionDialog();
    }
  }
Future<void> connectToDeviceFun() async {

globals.currentConnectionStream =
    globals.flutterReactiveBle.connectToDevice(
  id: globals.foundDevices.first.id,
  // prescanDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  // withServices: [],
);
    globals.logTexts = "";
    globals.connection = globals.currentConnectionStream.listen(
      (event) {
        globals.id = event.deviceId.toString();
        globals.connected = true;
        // globals.logTexts = "${globals.logTexts}Okay ${globals.count}/2\n";
        globals.logTexts = "${globals.logTexts}Connecting\n";
        globals.count == 2 ? globals.logTexts = "Ready to send data\n" : null;
        globals.numberOfMessagesReceived = 0;

        log('${globals.hexString}');

        setState(() {
          globals.count++;
        });

        //NOTIFICATION CHARACTERISTIC
        globals.notification = QualifiedCharacteristic(
          serviceId: _serviceUUID,
          characteristicId: _notifCharacteristic,
          deviceId: event.deviceId,
        );

        //WRITE TO CHARACTERISTIC
        globals.writeToCharacteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
          serviceId: _serviceUUID,
          characteristicId: _wCharacteristic,
          deviceId: event.deviceId,
        );
        refreshScreen();
      },
    );
  }
```

EDIT: changed connectToAdvertisingDevice to connectToDevice

EDIT 2: found out it takes a bit of time during the `DeviceConnectionState.connecting`

could there be a way to speed it up during the connection state or there is just no way?

Answer (score 1):

Use [connectToDevice](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_reactive_ble/latest/flutter_reactive_ble/FlutterReactiveBle/connectToDevice.html) instead of [connectToAdvertisingDevice](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_reactive_ble/latest/flutter_reactive_ble/FlutterReactiveBle/connectToAdvertisingDevice.html), which performs scan before connecting and therefore slows down the process.

Comment: Makes sense. Didn't really make a difference though

Comment: Since `connectToDeviceFun()` runs twice, I found out the second time always takes longer. Could it be scanning again or something?

Comment: Why is it running twice? It doesn't make sense to call connect twice in a row.

Comment: No idea, but it does. There is no loop to make it go twice. Anyway I found a workaround where I call for a `subscribeCharacteristic()` right after the initialization of the characteristics, making the connection faster

Comment: I see, you should cancel the subscription for scanForDevices after you get the match, otherwise it continues to scan nearby devices.

Comment: I'm already stopping the scan once it finds the device, but ty!

Comment: Okay so, the `connectToDeviceFun()` runs twice because when it's listening the stream, the second time it runs it's the actual time it connects. Between `DeviceConnectionState.connecting` and `DeviceConnectionState.connected` it takes it's time to establish the connection. I guess there is no actual way to make it faster?